# Раскрывающийся список (dropdown) на jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрипт раскрывающего списка (dropdown) на jQuery. Как сделать, что бы при клике на одну из выпадающих ссылок список закрывался, а на место `<a href="#"><span>Ссылки:</span> Все</a>` вместо "Все" подставлялся текст из ссылки, на которую нажали?

```js
jQuery('.user-columns-meta > a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (jQuery('.user-columns-meta').hasClass('open')) {
    jQuery('.user-columns-meta-links').slideUp();
    jQuery('.user-columns-meta').removeClass('open');
  } else {
    jQuery('.user-columns-meta-links').slideDown();
    jQuery('.user-columns-meta').addClass('open');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="columns_dropdown">
  <div class="user-columns-meta">
    <a href="#"><span>Ссылки:</span> Все</a>
  </div>
  <div class="user-columns-meta-links" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Все</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала, обернем текст внутри Вашего опенера который нужно заменить в `span`, не знаю зачем Вам `span` вокруг слова "Ссылка" (предположу что чтобы что-то подстилить), но я его оставлю и найду текст который нужно заменить посредством `id="textToReplace"` для наглядности. Затем вынесем функционал открытия и закрытия в отдельные функции, чтобы не дублировать код. Добавим слушатель на событие клик по нажатию на ссылку из дропдауна, где возьмем текст с того элемента на который нажали и заменим текст в элемент `id="textToReplace"` Вашего опенера.

```js
var openerHolder = jQuery('.user-columns-meta');
var opener = openerHolder.find('a');
var dropdown = jQuery('.user-columns-meta-links');
var dropdownLinks = dropdown.find('a');
var textToReplace = opener.find('#textToReplace');

function openDropdown(dropdown, opener) {
  dropdown.slideDown();
  opener.addClass('open');
}

function closeDropdown(dropdown, opener) {
  dropdown.slideUp();
  opener.removeClass('open');
}

opener.click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (openerHolder.hasClass('open')) {
    closeDropdown(dropdown, openerHolder);
    return;
  }
  openDropdown(dropdown, openerHolder);
});

dropdownLinks.click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var linkText = $(this).text();
  textToReplace.text(linkText);
  closeDropdown(dropdown, openerHolder);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="columns_dropdown">
  <div class="user-columns-meta">
    <a href="#"><span>Ссылки:</span> <span id="textToReplace">Все</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="user-columns-meta-links" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Все</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `span:last-child`  -  лучше использовать классы|id для привязки, чтобы не менять скрипты если верстка поменялась

Comment: @br3t согласен, но в данном случае не совсем понимаю зачем был первый спан, потому и указал об этом в сообщении, решил что при необходимости это заменят на то что будет более удобным. Но все же заменю на ID в примере для лучшей наглядности. Спасибо!